# Can't connect to server over local network but works fine from the Internet

Tags: networking, router, ssh, webserver

*This is **not** a typical NAT loopback block:* 
 Other users can connect to a server using its *external* IP from outside the server's local network, but I can't connect to it with its *external* or *internal* IPs (pings and non-standard services time out, HTTP requests and SSH connections return a 'Destinantion unreachable' error).

- This was a sudden change since I used to be able to connect from inside the local network with the server's internal IP
- The router has a public IP it uses for all devices in the network through NAT, with ports `22`, `80`, `443`, and some others forwarded to the server

Network diagram: 
 [image: Network diagram]

Comment: your network diagram is not too useful as you are mentioning an external IP and it seems that your router has it and probably uses port forwarding, if you could share more information, your IP/subnet, where you are connected from, your ping tries, tracepaths,....

Comment: and usually the router itself uses those ports so really can't port forward them. and trying to access the public IP / port forwarding rule also does not work from inside the LAN.

Comment: To build upon @Zina's comment, there's not enough information to even attempt to troubleshoot, however that seems firewall or DHCP/DNS related - check the router's firewall rules and your PC's, the router's system and firewall logs, and server firewall and SSH log, since the latter will immediately show if a request is even getting through. _(Just an FYI: WAN side SSH should never occur on port `22`, as doing so generally results in hundreds to thousands of connection requests daily and rejecting them consumes resources - If wanting to use `22`, forward a high port `>50000` to LAN side `22`.)_

Comment: I've re-checked the router settings and port 22 is not the one open on WAN, it's 22222 which is forwarded to 22 on LAN. But that doesn't change anything, because trying to connect to port 22 on LAN with the internal IP should be the exact same as connecting to 22222 on WAN with the external IP, and while the second one works, the first one doesn't. Router firewall doesn't seem to be an option on settings (my router is a TP-Link Deco).

Comment: @Pedro If the router is capable of NAT, it has to have a firewall interface - check the router's manual on TP-Link's support site to determine how to access it. Many router OEMs don't provide access to the firewall logs, and if the Deco does not, contact TP-Link tech support and ask if they can provide you with a debug firmware image, as debug images usually output the logs to a webserver port on the router's LAN IP.

Comment: and again, you should not be able to reach the external/public IP on port 22222 from internal LAN. to test your port forwarding you need to be outside the LAN side of the router...

Comment: Zina, I am not accessing port 22222 over LAN, because I know that 22222 is the external port. The one I used to be able to access from the LAN is 22, which is the one SSH listens on locally in the server. I don't need to 'test' the port forwarding because it works perfectly. @JW0914, I will try to get access to a debug firmware image; the current settings interface is extremely limited. Thanks for both your suggestions.